# Why am I getting some weird space between 2 forms?

Tags: html, css, forms

Any ideas on why am I getting some decent space between 2 forms(check picture) ?(it used to be only 1 form that had both of the buttons in  , but I had to create 2 for different functions.

```
<?php if ($product->isAvailable()): ?>
      <form action="<?php echo $href; ?>"class="f_add_cart"><div class="f_add_item"><button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-add btn-nocorners">adauga in cos</button></div></form>
      <?php endif; ?>
     <form method="post" action="<?php echo url_for('cart/updateCart');?>" class="f_add_cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1" maxlength="3" />
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $product->getId(); ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="<?php echo $sf_request->getUri(); ?>" />
      <div class="f_add_item"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link btn-wishlist" name="add_wishlist">adauga in wishlist</button></div>
    </form>     
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.product-over .product_price .regular_price sup{font-size:12px;} 
.product-over .product_price span.currency{display:none;} 
.product-over .product_price .old_price {color:white!important;} 
.product-over h3 {margin:0; padding:10px;height:auto!important;;text-align:center;} 
.product-over .f_add_cart{padding:10px;text-align:center} 
.product-over .f_add_item {padding:5px 0;border-top:1px solid #eaeaea;} 
.product-over button {font-size:11px; margin:5px 0;} 
.product-over .btn-wishlist {margin:0; padding:0;}
```

[image]

Comment: Because it's an image and not a page, I can't inspect the details, but I would very much suspect the CSS for this one. Especially `.f_add_item` and the CSS for `form` elements

Comment: @masj add css style. and upload working file.

Comment: Please share the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Modify `.product-over .f_add_cart{text-align:center}`

```
.product-over .product_price .regular_price sup{font-size:12px;}
.product-over .product_price span.currency{display:none;}
.product-over .product_price .old_price {color:white!important;}
.product-over h3 {margin:0; padding:10px;height:auto!important;;text-align:center;}
.product-over .f_add_cart{padding:10px;text-align:center}
.product-over .f_add_item {padding:5px 0;border-top:1px solid #eaeaea;}
.product-over button {font-size:11px; margin:5px 0;}
.product-over .btn-wishlist {margin:0; padding:0;}
```

[image]

Comment: I did'nt saw your code. So I am not able to help you. if I saw your website I will help you.

Comment: upload your file in snippet or jsfiddle. or share your wesite url.

Comment: I thought input take the space. check that.